# Best approach for customizing image with text on ios

Tags: ios, custom-component, quartz-core

I have a project to customize clothes ,let say a t-shirt, that have following features:

- change colors.
- add few lines of text ( <= 4) and change the font from a list.
- add image or photo to the t-shirt.
- rotate the t-shirt to custom back side.
- rotate the image and zoom in/out.
- save the result as a project locally and send it to a webservice ( i think to use NSDictionary/json ).
- save as an image.

so my question is :

Should I use multiples images to simulate colors changes. Or should I use QuartzCore ( I am not an expert in QuartzCore but if I have to use it I'll learn). Or is there a better approach for this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple way to do this is to render the T-Shirt image into a CGContext, then walk the rows and columns and change pixels showing a "strong" primary color to the desired tint. You would take a photo of a person wearing a bright red (or other primary color) t-shirt, then in your code only change pixels where the red color has a high luminance and saturation (i.e. the "r" value is over some threshold and the b and g components are low).

The modified image is then going to look a bit flat, as when you change the pixels to one value (the new tint) there will be no variation in luminance. To make this more realistic, you would want to make each pixel have the same luminance as it did before. You can do this by converting back and forth from RGB to a color space like HCL. Apple has a great doc on color (in the Mac section) that explains color spaces (google 'site:developer.apple.com "Color Spaces"')

To reach your goal, you will have to tackle these technologies:

- create a CGContext and render an image into it using Quartz
- figure out how to read each pixel (pixels can have alpha and different orderings)
- figure out a good way to identify the proper pixels (test by making these black or white)
- for each pixel you want to change, convert the RGB to HCL to get its luminance
- replace the pixel with a pixel of a different Color and Hue but the same Luminence
- use the CGContext to make a new image

If all this seems to difficult then you'll have to have different images for every color you want.

Comment: Thank you for this step by step explanation, your solution seem to be more elegant. i'll try this advanced stuff :).
i think that my choice will depend in how much ' t-shirt ' i have to custom. so for the moment i'll see if any one else have other ideas for me. 
but i love your solution so ill accept it :) .